How can I show onboard on top of my fullscreen electron app?
I'm creating an electron app which is going to be deployed on a linux tablet without keyboard.
I installed onboard and I'd like it to pop up when I select an input field. I managed to open whenever I want, but my app stays on top and I can't see the keyboard.
This is how I start my app
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron'); 
const { exec } = require('child_process');  
app.whenReady().then(() => {     
  const myWindow = new BrowserWindow({         
    fullscreen: true,         
    webPreferences: {             
      nodeIntegration: true,             
      contextIsolation: false         
    },     
  });      
  myWindow.loadFile('view/login.html');  
});

And how I open/close the keyboard
function openVirtualKeyboard() {
  console.log('Opening virtual keyboard');
  exec('onboard', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(`Error launching virtual keyboard: ${stderr}`);
    }
  });
}

function closeVirtualKeyboard() {
  console.log('Closing virtual keyboard');
  exec('pkill onboard', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(`Error closing virtual keyboard: ${stderr}`);
    }
  });
}

